# Regex to accept 7 to 10 digit number with dashes in between the number

Tags: javascript, regex

I would need help on regex for accepting any 7 digit to 10 digit number (no decimals) along with hyphen or spaces in between any where in the digit.

For example ,

Below are valid scenarios

```
0123456789
000-25-392-93
0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
0 1-2 3-4 5-6 7
```

Could some be able provide the best regex to accept this ?

Comment: Are consecutive spaces or dashes allowed(`0--1`)? How about mixed(`0 - 1`)?

Comment: it should accept space , hyphen  any where between the number 0--1 0r 0 -  1(but these are very rare scenario) is also possible. . i can further do a check to remove the - and and space later  in the code. But i need all the values with min 7 digit and max 10 digit number

Comment: Are you talking about phone numbers? Do you want to parse/verify phone numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(?:\d[- ]?){7,10}$` could also work.

- `\d`  for the digit.
- `[- ]` for the character after the number
- `?` for checking if there is one `space or -` after the last number
- `{7,10}` checks if it is between 7 and 10

Try it out:
https://regex101.com/r/Yx7iQ8/1

Comment: I didn't write my answer this way is because it's allowing `-` at the end which is not in between the numbers according OP's description.

Comment: This approach does not cover all possible valid (and invalid) variants.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^\d(?:[- ]*\d){6,9}$
```

- `^\d` starting with a digit.
- `(?:[- ]*\d){6,9}` followed by another digit with any amount of `-` or whitespaces inbetween, repeat 6 to 9 times, so 7 to 10 digits in total.
- `$` end of string.

See the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/HdyM7F/1/)

```js
const texts = [
  '0123456789',
  '000-25-392-93',
  '0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9',
  '0 1-2 3-4 5-6 7'
];

const regex = /^\d(?:[- ]*\d){6,9}$/;

console.log(texts.map(text => regex.test(text)));
```

Comment: perfect regex-only solution

Comment: good. but, ":?" is unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do that.

```js
const numbers = [
  "0123456789",
  "000-25-392-93",
  "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9",
  "0 1-2 3-4 5-6 7",
  "01234" ,          // not valid
  "33300409383850",  // not valid
  "123abc456def78"   // not valid
];

const valid = numbers.filter(num => {
  // count numerical digits by stripping out any non numerical characters
  //const len = num.replace(/\D/g, "").length;  // removes non numerical digits
   const len = num.replace(/[\s\-]/g, "").length;   // removes dashes and spaces
  
  
  // now we will only accept elements where their digit count is between 7 and 10
  return len > 6 && len < 11;
});

console.log(valid);
```

Comment: This will accept `0a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h`, which is not included in the rules given by OP.

Comment: I am aware of that. But my guess, is that the OP would want something like this @JoachimSauer